# Bound of sum of pseudorandom doubles

Tags: c++

So I have a function for generating random numbers:

```
void createRandom(int seed, int count, double min, double max, std::vector<double>& out) {
        srand( seed );
        out.reserve( count ); out.clear();
        while( count-- > 0 ) {
            out.push_back( min + (max-min) * ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) );
}
```

Let us assume I have 100 such numbers stored in a vector between 100 and 101, viz. `createRandom(22, 100, 100, 101, rand);`

My question is, will there be any difference of the theoretical lower and upper bound of the sum of all the numbers if I do:

1. Add them using loop and the `+` operator
2. `accumulate(rand.begin(), rand.end(), 0.0, mySum);`

The `mySum()` has the follwing implementation:

```
double mySum(double a, double b)
{
    return reducePrecision(a) + reducePrecision(b);
}

double reducePrecision( double x ) { 
    int exp; 
    double m = frexp(x, &exp); 
    m = roundFloat( m, 10 ); 
    return ldexp( m, exp ); 
}
double roundFloat( double x, int binaryDigits ) { 
    return ldexp( floor( ldexp( x, binaryDigits ) + 0.5 ), -binaryDigits ); 
}
```

If yes, why? Regards.

Comment: I would think that is going to depend entirely on the implementation of `mySum`.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Oops. I forgot to add those! Corrected!

Comment: @Jeet.Deir What about `roundFloat()`?

Comment: A great deal depends in the implementation of rand(). Typically, they have a small state which would impose a smaller upper and larger lower bound on the sums. Depends on the implementation.

Comment: I'd guess not, because `rand()` implementations I've seen don't produce more than 10 digits of random data (if my assumption about the operation of `roundFloat()` is correct.) But this is only a gut feeling, and I'm hardly mathematically proficient.

Comment: @yzt added! I am really puzzled!